# Mongo: how to group documents of a collection based on a key which is a property of a inner document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents, each representing a vote for a movie. Each document contains an inner document which describes the movie. Something like this

```
{movie: {_id: '123', name: 'fargo'}, vote: 'good'},
{movie: {_id: 'abc', name: 'fargo'}, vote: 'good'},
{movie: {_id: 'abc', name: 'fargo'}, vote: 'bad'},
{movie: {_id: 'xyz', name: 'fargo'}, vote: 'good'},
```

For whatever reason, over time, the same movie 'fargo' has been marked with different `_id`, but it is the same movie. In other words, the real key for a movie is the `name`, not `_id` as it usual to imagine.

Now what I would like to do is to `group`, via **aggregation** pipeline, all movies with the same `name`, ignoring the fact that they may have different `_id`s, and count the number of ***good*** and ***bad*** votes they have received.

So, in the case of the example, I would like to receive as result of the aggregation something like

```
{name: 'fargo', votes: [
  {vote: 'good', count: 3},
  {vote: 'bad', count: 1}
]}
```

So far I have tried

`{$group: {_id: {movieName: "$movie.name", vote: "$vote"}, count: {$sum: 1}, }}`

but with no luck.

Any suggestion to understand where I make a mistake would be appreciated.

Comment: [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
[
    {$project: {
      _id: "$movie.name",
      "good": {$cond: {if: {$eq: ["$vote","good"]}, then: 1, else: 0}},
      "bad": {$cond: {if: {$eq: ["$vote","bad"]}, then: 1, else: 0}}
    }},
    {$group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      good: {$sum: "$good"},
      bad: {$sum: "$bad"}
    }}
]
```

Output (for your sample documents):

```
{
  "_id" : "fargo",
  "good" : 3.0,
  "bad" : 1.0
}
```

Explanation of the pipeline stages:

1. Project: use the name of the move as `_id` and represent *good* and *bad* votes numerically
2. Group: count each vote individually for every film